# Auctex cannot find a working TeX distribution on spacemacs with Osx ElCapitan

Tags: latex, osx-elcapitan, auctex, spacemacs

I get the following error when I try to build latex from spacemacs text editor :

> TeX-command: Error : Auctex cannot find a working TeX distribution.
>   Make sure you have one and that Tex binaries are in PATH environment
>   variable. If fyou are using OSX El Capitain or later remember to add
>   /Library/TeX/textbin/ to your path

I have installed MacText torrent linked on the official site : https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

The /Library/TeX/textbin/ path doesn't exist for me even if I install MacTex.

I have tried to add Library/TeX/textbin to my path but it didn't work.

The TeXShop text editor is building LaTeX correctly somehow.

How can I fix my problem and where is my Tex distribution ? Do I need to change my path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after debugging it with him. We realized that he forgot the leading / in his path. So Spacemacs was searching in ~/Library instead on /Libraby